# Amazon s3 streaming in mule

Tags: java, amazon-s3, streaming, mule

I have a requirement to stream large files from amazon s3, process them(transform) and upload them back to s3. Is there a cleaner way this can be achieved in mule.

The way I am trying is the use s3-get object and then add a mule transformer, which will read the input stream and process and then try to write back. Sample code below:

```
 <s3:config name="AmazonS3" accessKey="XXXXXX" secretKey="XXXXXX" doc:name="S3" />
 <s3:get-object-content config-ref="AmazonS3"
            bucketName="XXXXXX"
            />
  <custom-transformer class="com.myapp.FileStreamer"
            doc:name="Stream S3 files" />
```

The transformer code looks like....

```
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
            throws TransformerException {
    CSVReader reader = null;

    InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) message.getPayload();

    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, '\0');
     String[] line=null;
     while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
    }
  catch (IOException e1) {
    ......
}...............
```

I am not able to see the sop printed for large files.

Comment: Cleaner than what? What have you tried? I can't answer your question, but if you provide more details, other people can maybe.

Answer (score 0):

check this connector for Amazon S3: http://mulesoft.github.io/s3-connector
I think you could use the `get-object` and `create-object` operations to retrieve and upload files as you need.
HTH, Marcos.

Comment: Hello Marcos..thanks for responding..However, as said I need a way to do streaming with s3..believe get and create work with any issues for smaller files..I have updated the question with code sample and details

Comment: I think you are already streaming the content file. Did you received any error for large files? You could also check the concrete input stream class received in the transformer to see if the content is stored in memory or not. Also, if you need to process while downloading and uploading the file you could try setting the payload with an output stream inside the transformer.

Comment: I did not receive any errors. the processing just stops there. I now intermittently see some content, but for large files, it just does not stream completely. The flow reads partial contents of the file and just stops there.

Comment: What says the log file in mule and amazon? Please increase the log level to debug. May be the connection timed out or amazon is slowing down it.

Comment: @RST Hey What happened to this ? In the end were you able to achieve streaming which you needed ? I have a similar requirement.